# Custom Confirm function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been looking to see exactly how the default confirm button works to no avail, if anyone has any good technical documentation that would be appreciated.

```js
function showAlert() {
  var container = document.getElementById("alertContainer");
  var overlay = document.getElementById("alertOverlay");
  if (container.style.display === "block") {
    container.style.display = "none";
    overlay.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    container.style.display = "block";
    overlay.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function alert(text) {
  showAlert();

  $(alertHeader).html("Alert!");
  $(alertHeader).css('text-align', 'center');

  $(alertText).html(text);
  $(alertText).css('text-align', 'center');
}

function confirm(text) {
  showAlert();

  $(alertHeader).html("Confirm");
  $(alertHeader).css('text-align', 'center');

  $(alertText).html(text);
  $(alertText).css('text-align', 'center');

  return true; //does not wait for user input just confirms and runs the code

}


function commitRow(btn) {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you would like to commit this row?")) {
    //does stuff
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="alertContainer">
  <h1 id="alertHeader">
    <center>Alert!</center>
  </h1>
  <p id="alertText">Test Text</p>
  <center>
    <button id="alertButton1" class="alertButtons" onclick="showAlert()">Confirm</button>
    <button id="alertButton2" class="alertButtons" onclick="showAlert()">Cancel</button>
  </center>
</div>

<div id="alertOverlay"></div>
```

I've got as far as having my function automatically confirm, however obviously i need the function to wait until a decision is made by the user.

confirm() is a default function in javascript i believe. I have overwritten that function by creating a function with the same name. I did this so i could style it consistently with the alerts(also a default function of which i overwrote).

In the function commitRow(btn), which is where I commit the data in a the row of the table into our database. **By default, if(confirm("") will wait for the user to press Ok or cancel. I need my confirm to behave the same way.** Show Alert and Alert aren't really important to the question, pay attention to the comments in the confirm function and the commitRow function.
Thank you in advanced

Comment: Where is the `showAlert()` function defininition?

Comment: Sorry, see edit

Comment: You're going to need a button to wait for the confirm

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want your program to do. The buttons call `showAlert()` (which is missing from your "Run code snippet". That method only toggles the visibility of the `container` and `overlay` (which doesn't exist in your html).

Comment: See edit. at the bottom of my question."By default, if(confirm("") will wait for the user to press Ok or cancel. I need my confirm to behave the same way."

Comment: I admit i didnt title this correctly. I was meant to write, "Custom Confirm Function"

Comment: I agree with @bcr666 that you miss part of HTML with element with id `alertOverlay`.

Comment: Well, the default `confirm()` displays a popup dialog that has 2 buttons on it. Since you overrode the method, the default behavior is not going to happen. That means you are going to have to implement your own buttons on your confirm panel.

Comment: Okay I'll add it in, but this is not what i quite understand about this website. I only included the code I thought you'd need. to answer the question. The code which is being asked for is just filler stuff with no relevance to the question - furthermore will not influence the answer.

Comment: Here is an example of implementing a Custom Confirm https://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3

Comment: @bcr666 that's what i'm asking for, how will i go about replicating the behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Here is simply modification of your code which is answer for your question. Of course you have to add some css styles and js logic.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="show alert" class="alertButtons" onclick="showAlert()">Show popup</button>
        <div id="alertContainer" style="display: none;">
          <h1 id="alertHeader">
            <center>Alert!</center>
          </h1>
          <p id="alertText">Are you sure you would like to commit this row</p>
          <center>
            <button id="alertButton1" class="alertButtons" onclick="confirm()">Confirm</button>
            <button id="alertButton2" class="alertButtons" onclick="cancel()">Cancel</button>
          </center>
          <div id="alertOverlay"></div>
        </div>

    <script>
        function showAlert() {
            var container = document.getElementById("alertContainer");
            var overlay = document.getElementById("alertOverlay");
            if (container.style.display === "block") {
                container.style.display = "none";
                overlay.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                container.style.display = "block";
                overlay.style.display = "block";
            }
        }

        function confirm() {
          showAlert();
          commitRow();
        }

        function commitRow() {
            console.log("Commit row");
            //does stuff
        }

        function cancel() {
            console.log("Cancel");
            //does stuff
        }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```